# Post on Facebook using with previous date

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, dom-events

Changing Facebook Post Date with Graph API
facebook facebook-graph-api
I can post on my wall with Graph API.

Using FB nod and graph,now I have to post on Facebook using previous date
Then, I can change their date manually. Is it possible to change the date of a post or create a new post with a past date through Graph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks and regards.
 i find the solution myself for post on facebook using previous date. 
use

> backdated_time: date(in timeStamp)